# foreach loop inside $output

Tags: php, foreach

I'm trying to run a foreach loop inside `$output = '';` and later `echo $output;`.
I can print any other variable like this `'.$row["name"].'` inside `$output = '';` but can do a foreach loop.

```
if(isset($_POST["id"]))
    {

      $output = '';
      $query = mysqli_query($databaseLink, "SELECT * FROM test WHERE test_id = '".$_POST["id"]."'");
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
      {
        $output .= '
        <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field custom-check col s4">
        <h4 class="project-label-display project-label-display-center" > Practice Vertical </h4>
        '$list_id= explode(",", $row["pet_id"]);
        foreach($list_id as $value) {
        <br>
        print $value;
        <br> }'
    ';
      }
      echo $output;
    }
```

The thing is I cant  forech loop inside `$output .= ' ';` , it does not work.

Okay here is the thing, this code here

```
$list_id= explode(",", $row["pet_id"]);
foreach($list_id as $value) {
    <br>
    print $value;
    <br>
}
```

runs just fine if I run it outside `$output .= '       ';`.

Any php code that goes inside `$output .= '  '`  should be wrapped inside another `'. .'` or `' '`  else it becomes a simple text. so if i want to print a variable i have to do it like this `'.$count.'`. But I cant use a loop.

Comment: why don't you try it first? That way you'll know

Comment: Never do this: `WHERE test_id = '".$_POST["test_id"]."'"` Read up on prepared statements and sql injection

Comment: I have tried it and does not work.

Comment: Is this the exact code you used? This part: `Practice Vertical </h4>

    '$list_id` can't even run without a semicolon?

Comment: yes to use php inside i need to put  codes inside  ' //code'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't close your `<div>s` properly, nor did you assign the output to `$output` properly. I fixed the positions of the single apostrophes `'` so they make sense.

**Here is the corrected code:**

```
if(isset($_POST["test_id"]))
{
   $output = '';
   $query = mysqli_query($databaseLink, "SELECT * FROM test WHERE test_id = '".$_POST["test_id"]."'");

   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
   {
      $output .= '
      <div class="row">
      <div class="input-field custom-check col s4">
      <h4 class="project-label-display project-label-display-center"> Practice Vertical </h4>';

       $list_id= explode(",", $row["pet_id"]);
       foreach($list_id as $value)
       {
          $output .= '<br>'.$value.'<br>';
       }
       $output .= '</div>
       </div>';
    }

  echo $output;
}
```

Comment: this approach does not work because everything inside `$output.=' //are recognized as simple text ' ;` unless you use  `'.//code.'`  or  `' //code '`

Comment: @cooper It works, I just  had an extra `}` in there. Try again please.

Comment: ahh ill try.. will let you know

Comment: @cooper Did it work? Just copy and paste the whole code and try it, though i don't see where the `$databaseLink` is coming from, I hope you have a valid mysqli connection above that you didn't show.

Comment: No it didnt work. well the code is the same. I have updated the question.

Comment: @cooper do you have a valid mysqli connection? And.. my code is not the same as yours. I changed the placements of the `'` so that the `foreach` is not inside the `$output`, though the `$output` still gets updated. I don't understand how this does not work. If you have a valid mysqli connection, then do this `$list_id= explode(",", $row["pet_id"]); print_r($list_id)` and check that it is getting proper values;

Answer (score 0):

A simple approach:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
{
    $output .= '
        <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field custom-check col s4">
        <h4 class="project-label-display project-label-display-center" > Practice Vertical </h4>';

    // Add every id to your output explicictly
    $list_id = explode(",", $row["pet_id"]);
    foreach($list_id as $value) {
        $output .= '<br>' . $value . '<br>';
    }

    $output .= '</div>';
}
```

Comment: this approach does not work because everything inside `$output.=' //are recognized as simple text ' ;` unless you use  `'.//code.'`  or  `' //code '`

Comment: `//code` is your php code. so to run a php code inside `$output = '       ';` you  wrap the code with`'. .'` or  `' '`.

Comment: Please, read my answer carefully. There's __no code__ inside `' '`.

Comment: here is the thing. Any php code that goes inside ` $output .= '  ' `  should be wrapped inside another `'. .'` or ` ' ' `  else it becomes a simple text. so if i want to print a variable i have to do it like this `'.$count.' `.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to explain.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code:

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST["id"]))
    {

      $output = '';
      $query = mysqli_query($databaseLink, "SELECT * FROM test WHERE test_id = '".$_POST["id"]."'");
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
      {
        $output .= '
        <div class="row">
        <div class="input-field custom-check col s4">
        <h4 class="project-label-display project-label-display-center" > Practice Vertical </h4>';
        $list_id= explode(",", $row["pet_id"]);
        foreach($list_id as $value) {
              $output = $output."<br>".$value."<br>";
        }
        $output .= '</div>';
      }
      echo $output;
    }
?>
```